# Can SOLR/Lucene report calculated score of extra named documents, even if they're not in top N results?

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search

I'd like to submit a query to SOLR/Lucene, plus a list of document IDs. From the query, I'd like the usual top-N scored results, but I'd also like to get the scores for the named documents... no matter how low they are.

Can anyone think of an easy/supported way to do this in a single index scan, where the scores for the 'added' (non-ranking/pinned-for-inclusion) docs are comparable/same-scaled as those for the top-N results? (Patching SOLR with specialized classes would be OK; I figure that's what I may have to do if there's no existing support.)

Or failing that, could it be simulated with a followup query, ideally in a way that the named-document scores could be scaled to be roughly comparable to the top-N for the reference query?

Alternatively -- and perhaps as good or better for my intended use -- could I make a single request against a SOLR/Lucene index which includes M (with M=2 or more) distinct queries, and return the results that are in the top-N for any of the M queries, and for every result include its score against all M of the distinct queries?

(Even in my above formulation, the list of documents that I want scored along with a new query will typically have been the results from a prior query.)

Solutions or even just fragments of possible approaches appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand properly what you want to achieve but wouldn't a simple

```
 q: (somequery) OR id: (1 OR 2 OR 4)
```

be enough?
If you would want both parts to be boosted by the same scale (I am not sure if this isn't the default behaviour of Solr) you would want to use dismax or edismax and your query would change to something like:

```
 q: (somequery)^10 OR id: (1 OR 2 OR 4)^10
```

You would then have both the elements defined by the IDs and the query results scored the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; I've done a few experiments along those lines. 

To clarify and illustrate how this differs from my desired result, a compound query like this would: 

(1) give me just 'rows' total results, rather than 'rows' results for 'somequery' and then scores for the other IDs; 

(2) not necessarily include all the docs after the OR in the top results; 

(3) give scores for the ID docs dissimilar from what their pure score for 'somequery' would be. (Maybe this last thing could be offset with the right boosts/rescaling.)

Answer (score 0):

To self-answer, reporting what I've found since posting...

One clumsy option is the [`explainOther`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#explainOther) parameter, which takes another query. (This query could be a OR list of interesting document IDs.) The response will then include a full scoring explanation for documents which match this other query. `explainOther` only has effect when combined with the also-required `debugQuery` parameter.

All that debug/explain information is overkill for the need, but may be useful, or the code paths that implement it might provide a guide to making a hypothetical new more narrowly-focused 'scoreOther' option.

Another option would be to make use of pseudo-field calculated using the [`query()`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#query) function to report how any set of results score on some other query/queries. So if for example the original document set was the top-N from query_A, and then those are the exact documents that you also want to score against query_B, you would execute query_A again with a reporting-field `…&fl=bscore:query({!dismax v="query_B"})&…`. Then the document's scores against query_B would be included in the output (as `bscore`).

Finally, the [result-grouping](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) functionality can be used both collect the top-N for one query and scores for lesser documents intersecting with other queries in one go. For example, if querying for query_B and adding `…&group=true&group.query=query_B&group.query=query_A&…`, you'll get back groups that satisfy query_B (ranked by query_B), and that satisfy both query_B and query_A (but again ranked by query_B). This could be mixed with the functional field above to get the scores by another query (like query_A) as well.

However, all groups will share the same sort order (from either the master query or something specified by a `group.sort` parameter), so it's not currently possible (SOLR-4.0.0-beta) to get several top-N results according to different scorings, just the top-Ns according to one scoring, limited by certain groups. (There's a [comment in the source code](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/trunk/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/Grouping.java#L295) suggesting alternate sorts per group may be envisioned as a future capability.)